# Continuous functions and product topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

My topology textbook states that

*the function $\mathrm h: X \rightarrow Y$ from topological space $\mathrm X$ to topological space $\mathrm Y$ is continuous if and only if the function $\mathrm k = i \times h: X \rightarrow X \times Y$ defined by $\mathrm k(x) = (x,h(x))$ for every $\mathrm x \in X$, is an homeomorphism of $\mathrm X$ with the subspace $\Gamma_h$ of $\mathrm X \times Y$*

where $\mathrm i$ is the canonical inclusion and $\mathrm \Gamma_h = \{ (x,y) \in X \times Y | y = h(x) \}$.

I'm interested only in the necessary condition. The proof given is as follows:

*Let i': $\mathrm \Gamma_h \rightarrow X \times Y$ be the canonical inclusion and k': $\mathrm X \rightarrow \Gamma_h$ the function such that k $\mathrm = i' \circ k': X \rightarrow X \times Y$.*
*If $\mathrm k'$ is an homeomorphism, $\mathrm k$ is continuous, therefore $\mathrm h = q \circ k$ is continuous*

where q: $\Gamma_h \rightarrow$ Y is the canonical projection.

I do understand every passage of the proof, but **why do I have to introduce the homeomorphism $\mathrm k$'?** If, by hypothesis, $\mathrm k$ is an homeomorphism, can't I just conclude that $\mathrm h$ is continuous because $\mathrm h = q \circ k$?

Comment: Let us write $\jmath:\Gamma_h\longrightarrow X\times Y$ for the canonical inclusion and $\pi_Y:X\times X\longrightarrow Y$ for the canonical projection. Both maps are continuous (the first because $\Gamma_h$ is endowed with the subspace topology and the second because $X\times Y$ is endowed with the product topology). If $(\mathsf{id}_X, h):X\longrightarrow \Gamma_h$ is continuous then $h=p_Y\circ \jmath\circ (\mathsf{id}_X, h)$ is continuous.

Comment: @PtF Why didn't you give an official answer to the question?